Error: Emit attempted before Angular Webpack plugin initialization. on npm start
Error: Emit attempted before Angular Webpack plugin initialization.
Error: Failed to initialize Angular compilation - The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=5.2.0 and <5.3.0 but 5.4.5 was found instead.
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
× Failed to compile.
What causes this error? I am using typescript of Version 5.4.5
Not able to compile, but it says compilation failed

Which version of Angular do you use? Like the second error tells you, it seems that the typescript version is not compatible.

@JSONDerulo I am using angular 17.2

As you can read in the compatibility table, Angular 17.2 is not compatible with TypeScript version 5.4.5

so do i need to change the code or thechange typescript version?

Changing the code doesn't change anything. You are using 2 libraries with incompatible versions. Downgrading the TypeScript version will probably fix it. You can also try updating to Angular 17.3

The error message is clear enough: You can't use the installed Angular version with TypeScript 5.4.5, which is installed.
You can upgrade Angular to the latest version, or downgrade TypeScript to 5.2.

Downgraded typescript to 5.2 v resolved the issues
